# How to sync music from pc to iphone music library programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ipod, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have downloaded music from website url or from pc via sharing application and stored it to local document directory. Now I want to add stored musics from local directory to device's music library programmatically.

So how to sync music from local directory to a iphone/ipod/ipad device's music library programmatically without using iTunes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to create your own library within your app in order to do this as Apple only allows read access to the iPod Music Library on iOS. If you do want to create your own in-app library then wi-fi or bluetooth file sharing would be the way to go.

Comment: @amergin Thanks for reply. I know Apple only allows read access to the iPod Music Library on iOS, but is it possible to save/write music to iPod Music Library programmatically any way? Please tell me how to do it? Is there any example?

Comment: No, there's no way to write to the iPod Music Library on the device unless you're jailbroken. You can, of course, write to the library on your mac or pc then sync it.

Comment: @amergin Can you tell me how to write library on mac or pc?

Comment: It's years since I did anything with this on OSX so I can't really help - you could try looking at ScriptingBridge-https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html , titl - http://code.google.com/p/titl/ or picardplugins - http://code.google.com/p/picardplugins/wiki/LibraryFile but I'm not sure they are what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

When your iPhone is plugged into your computer, open iTunes automatically and iTunes to sync your music.